# Get the mouse position on an object or GridHelper object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to be able to find the mouse position if the mouse is on a Cube/Sphere Geometry, or if it is on the ground (using a GridHelper)

I'm trying to make shapes where a users mouse is, I have all the code needed to make the shapes, but I'm having trouble getting the position right

This is the code that gave me the best results

```
var vec = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse
var pos = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse

vec.set(
  ( container.offsetWidth / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
  - ( container.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
   0.5
);

vec.unproject( camera );
vec.sub( camera.position ).normalize();

var distance = - camera.position.z / vec.z;
pos.copy( camera.position ).add( vec.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
```

Althoough this seems to relate more to where the camera is and even then, it's not exactly where the camera is,  I've also tried re-using other code, say from [the interactive cubes example that uses a Raycaster from three js](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) and but it also seemed a bit random for when it would detect an intersection.

What should happen if the user puts their mouse on the grid, I should get the coordinates (i.e. 2.4, -5, 0, of course much more precise than that) and say the user puts their mouse on a shape, the coordinates of here the mouse is in the scene (touching the shape) (i.e. 2.4, -5, 3)